# How to print mysql report and export to excel

Tags: php, mysql, reporting, export-to-excel, database-replication

I have an employees database that I have replicated into master/slave and I would like to produce a report that should be printable and exportable to excel.I am using xampp.Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Replication</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//connecting to the master server
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","justin","topdeveloper") or $con = false;
//if connection to the master server fails don\t connect to the slave
if ($con!=false) {
mysql_close($con);
//connecting to the slave server
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");

mysql_Select_db('clients',$con);
//the timestampdiff function gets the age of the person by subtracting the date_of_birth from the current date
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `first_name`,`second_name`,`last_name`,`id_number`,`phone_number`,`home_town`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,date_of_birth,CURDATE()) AS `age` FROM `bio_data` ORDER BY age DESC");
     echo "<table border='1'>";
           echo "<tr align='center'>";  
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."First Name"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Second Name"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Last Name"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Id Number"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Phone Number"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Home Town"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Age"."</font></th>";
            echo "</tr>";   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            //echo "<table border='1'>";
            echo "<tr align='center' >";    
            echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$row['first_name']."</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$row['second_name']."</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['last_name']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['id_number']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['phone_number']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['home_town']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['age']. "</font></td>";            
            echo "</tr>";   


}
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_close($con);

}

?>


</body>
</html>
```

At the moment i am able to produce display the records on html page

Comment: take a look at phpExcel, you will have to do some formatting of the data so it can be pushed into phpExcel  URL: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/.  The documentation is not bad.  Might I also suggest you move away from the mysql driver and use the PDO Mysqli driver instead...

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) demo code than implement cording to your requirement.

> PHPExcel is a library written in pure PHP and providing a set of classes that allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats, like Excel (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007 (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx, CSV, Libre/OpenOffice Calc .ods, Gnumeric, PDF, HTML, ... This project is built around Microsoft's OpenXML standard and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add an excel class and write a function to download the file(working fine), but I have a problem that the file auto downloads when i load my main file(index.php).The following are my main php files.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Replication APP</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>Replication APP</h1>
</div>

<div id="content">

<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("includes/config.php");
include("includes/excelwriter.class.php");

//the timestampdiff function gets the age of the person by subtracting the date_of_birth from the current date
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `first_name`,`second_name`,`last_name`,`id_number`,`phone_number`,`home_town`, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,date_of_birth,CURDATE()) AS `age` FROM `bio_data` ORDER BY age DESC");
     echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";
           echo "<tr align='center'>";  
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."First Name"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Second Name"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Last Name"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Id Number"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Phone Number"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Home Town"."</font></th>";
            echo"<th><font color='black'>" ."Age"."</font></th>";
            echo "</tr>";   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            //echo "<table border='1'>";
            echo "<tr align='center' >";    
            echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$row['first_name']."</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$row['second_name']."</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['last_name']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['id_number']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['phone_number']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['home_town']. "</font></td>";
            echo"<td><font color='black'>". $row['age']. "</font></td>";            
            echo "</tr>";



}

 echo "</table>";

 require_once("export.php");
 $export=download();
 ?>

<!--<a href="#" onClick=window.location='report.xls';>Export to Excel</a>-->
<a href="<?php echo $export;?>"> Export to Excel </a>

</div>


<div id="footer">
Copyright &copy Justin 2015
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

export.php:

```
 <?php
error_reporting(0);
function download()
{
    $excel=new ExcelWriter("report.xls");

if(!$excel)
{
echo $excel->error;
}
else
{
$A=array("First Name","Second Name","Last Name","Id Number","Phone Number","Home Town","Age");
$excel->writeLine($A);
}


// now fetch data from database table, there is a new line create each time loop runs

if(!$result=mysql_query("SELECT `first_name`,`second_name`,`last_name`,`id_number`,`phone_number`,`home_town`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,date_of_birth,CURDATE()) AS `age` FROM `bio_data` ORDER BY age DESC"))
{
    echo "something terrible happened";
}
else{
 while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $Arr=array($res['first_name'],$res['second_name'],$res['last_name'],$res['id_number'],$res['phone_number'],$res['home_town'],$res['age']);
 $excel->writeLine($Arr);
 }
}
    if(file_exists($excel))
    {
        header('Content-Description:File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type:application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='.basename($excel));
        header('Expires:0');
        header('Cache-Control:must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma:public');
        header('Content-Length:'.filesize($excel));
        readfile($excel);
        exit;
    }

}

?>
```

excelwriter.class.php:

```
<?php

     /*
     * Class is used for save the data into microsoft excel format.
     * It takes data into array or you can write data column vise.
     */


    Class ExcelWriter
    {

        var $fp=null;
        var $error;
        var $state="CLOSED";
        var $newRow=false;

        /*
        * @Params : $file  : file name of excel file to be created.
        * @Return : On Success Valid File Pointer to file
        *           On Failure return false  
        */

        function ExcelWriter($file="")
        {
            return $this->open($file);
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $file  : file name of excel file to be created.
        *           if you are using file name with directory i.e. test/myFile.xls
        *           then the directory must be existed on the system and have permissioned properly
        *           to write the file.
        * @Return : On Success Valid File Pointer to file
        *           On Failure return false  
        */
        function open($file)
        {
            if($this->state!="CLOSED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Another file is opend .Close it to save the file";
                return false;
            }   

            if(!empty($file))
            {
                $this->fp=@fopen($file,"w+");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->error="Usage : New ExcelWriter('fileName')";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->fp==false)
            {
                $this->error="Error: Unable to open/create File.You may not have permmsion to write the file.";
                return false;
            }
            $this->state="OPENED";
            fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetHeader());
            return $this->fp;
        }

        function close()
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->newRow)
            {
                fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
                $this->newRow=false;
            }

            fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetFooter());
            fclose($this->fp);
            $this->state="CLOSED";
            return ;
        }
        /* @Params : Void
        *  @return : Void
        * This function write the header of Excel file.
        */

        function GetHeader()
        {
            $header = <<<EOH
                <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
                xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

                <head>
                <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
                <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
                 <o:DocumentProperties>
                  <o:LastAuthor>Sriram</o:LastAuthor>
                  <o:LastSaved>2005-01-02T07:46:23Z</o:LastSaved>
                  <o:Version>10.2625</o:Version>
                 </o:DocumentProperties>
                 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                  <o:DownloadComponents/>
                 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                </xml><![endif]-->
                <style>
                <!--table
                    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
                    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
                @page
                    {margin:1.0in .75in 1.0in .75in;
                    mso-header-margin:.5in;
                    mso-footer-margin:.5in;}
                tr
                    {mso-height-source:auto;}
                col
                    {mso-width-source:auto;}
                br
                    {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
                .style0
                    {mso-number-format:General;
                    text-align:general;
                    vertical-align:bottom;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    mso-rotate:0;
                    mso-background-source:auto;
                    mso-pattern:auto;
                    color:windowtext;
                    font-size:10.0pt;
                    font-weight:400;
                    font-style:normal;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                    mso-font-charset:0;
                    border:none;
                    mso-protection:locked visible;
                    mso-style-name:Normal;
                    mso-style-id:0;}
                td
                    {mso-style-parent:style0;
                    padding-top:1px;
                    padding-right:1px;
                    padding-left:1px;
                    mso-ignore:padding;
                    color:windowtext;
                    font-size:10.0pt;
                    font-weight:400;
                    font-style:normal;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                    mso-font-charset:0;
                    mso-number-format:General;
                    text-align:general;
                    vertical-align:bottom;
                    border:none;
                    mso-background-source:auto;
                    mso-pattern:auto;
                    mso-protection:locked visible;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    mso-rotate:0;}
                .xl24
                    {mso-style-parent:style0;
                    white-space:normal;}
                -->
                </style>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
                 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
                  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
                   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                    <x:Name>srirmam</x:Name>
                    <x:WorksheetOptions>
                     <x:Selected/>
                     <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>
                     <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
                     <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
                    </x:WorksheetOptions>
                   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
                  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
                  <x:WindowHeight>10005</x:WindowHeight>
                  <x:WindowWidth>10005</x:WindowWidth>
                  <x:WindowTopX>120</x:WindowTopX>
                  <x:WindowTopY>135</x:WindowTopY>
                  <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
                  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
                 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
                </xml><![endif]-->
                </head>

                <body link=blue vlink=purple>
                <table x:str border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style='border-collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed;'>
EOH;
            return $header;
        }

        function GetFooter()
        {
            return "</table></body></html>";
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $line_arr: An valid array 
        * @Return : Void
        */

        function writeLine($line_arr)
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if(!is_array($line_arr))
            {
                $this->error="Error : Argument is not valid. Supply an valid Array.";
                return false;
            }
            fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
            foreach($line_arr as $col)
                fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$col</td>");
            fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
        }

        /*
        * @Params : Void
        * @Return : Void
        */
        function writeRow()
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->newRow==false)
                fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
            else
                fwrite($this->fp,"</tr><tr>");
            $this->newRow=true; 
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $value : Coloumn Value
        * @Return : Void
        */
        function writeCol($value)
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$value</td>");
        }
    }
?>
```

please help.any suggestions on improvement